# Webauthn API ignores most extensions (largeBlob)

Tags: javascript, html, webauthn

Im trying to implement Webauthn on my side and want to the largeBlob extension. Chrome, as well as Safari, are ignoring the option, and its paramenters, completely though. I have created a simulated authenticator with largeBlob support, and one without, in Chromes Webauthn debugger but both behave the exact same way.

Here is the basic example code, most of has been taken directly from w3c documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script>
        var publicKey = {
            // Here are the extensions (as "inputs")
            extensions: {
                largeBlob: {
                    support: "required",
                },
            },
            authenticatorSelection: {
                requireResidentKey: true,
            },
            challenge: new Uint8Array(16) /* from the server */,
            rp: {
                name: "Example CORP",
                id: "localhost"
            },
            user: {
                id: new Uint8Array(16) /* from the server */,
                name: "jdoe@example.com",
                displayName: "John Doe"
            },
            pubKeyCredParams: [
                {
                    type: "public-key",
                    alg: -7
                }
            ]
        };
        function auth() {
            navigator.credentials.create({ publicKey })
                .then(function (newCredentialInfo) {
                    var myBuffer = newCredentialInfo.getClientExtensionResults();
                    console.log(myBuffer);
                    // myBuffer will contain the result of any of the processing of the "loc" and "uvi" extensions
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="auth()">Auth</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I broke down the code to the minimal reproducable example, tried it in multiple browsers and with different wrapper libraries.

According to the [official spec](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-large-blob-extension), the process should throw when no authenticator with largeBlob support becomes avaliable. Instead it just continues, creates the credential without the extension and does not return the [appropriate result](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#dictdef-authenticationextensionslargebloboutputs)

Comment: I don't believe any shipping mainstream browser currently supports largeBlob

Comment: @Tim really? It says [here](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5657899357437952) that its supposed to ship in version 88 of chrome and we are on 108 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features is enabled for experimentation with largeBlob. There is not currently a compelling use for largeBlob in web browsers and so support remains behind a flag.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Chrome still dosent seem to write or retrieve any data, but also dosent just ignore the extension anymore.

Comment: Once upon a time it did work but, since it hasn't been launched, it's possible that it has regressed. You can see the CTAP2 traffic from Chrome in chrome://device-log. It it looks like there's a bug, you can report at crbug.com; mention that it's for "Blink>WebAuthentication".